# Hiding and showing an image onMouseOver & onMouseOut - image re-appears instantly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

I wrote the following jquery script.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
          $(document).ready(function(){
           $('#Oval-1').on('mouseover', function(e) {
                $("#Oval-1").fadeOut();
            });
                $('#Oval-1').on('mouseout', function(e) {
                         $("#Oval-1").fadeIn();
                 });
          });
        </script>
```

Oval-1 ist the id of an svg image on my page. On mouseover i would like the image to fadeout, on mouseout I would like the image to fadein. However, doing it like I did, the image does fade out but immediately fades in again, giving it the appearance of 'blinking' once. Where am I going wrong here?

This is my div containing the svg:

```
<div class="wrapper">
        <svg width="1024px" height="279px" viewBox="0 0 1024 279" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<!-- Generator: Sketch 3.6.1 (26313) - http://www.bohemiancoding.com/sketch -->
<title>map png</title>
<desc>Created with Sketch.</desc>
<defs></defs>
<g id="geschichte" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
    <g id="Desktop-Landscape" transform="translate(-145.000000, -332.000000)">
        <g id="map" transform="translate(107.000000, 246.000000)">
            <g id="mapback" transform="translate(38.000000, 86.000000)">
                <g id="map-png">


// there are further paths here, I took out for now

                                            <ellipse id="Oval-1" fill="#0B619B" opacity="0.141849347" cx="929.5" cy="94.5" rx="94.5" ry="94.5"></ellipse>


                </g>
            </g>
        </g>
    </g>
</g>
```

PS : I have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21356492/javascript-html-hiding-and-showing-images-onmouseover-and-onmouseout), but I am concerned with jquery here, not with vanilla js.

Comment: The issue here is probably that the image get's hidden, thus the `mouseout` will be triggered by that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually approach this effortlessly with CSS

```
#Oval-1 {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 400ms ease;
}

#Oval-1:hover {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

Comment: thank you. i just tried it, still the same problem though, i.e. it does not stay like this for a long time and just changes back to showing the image.

Comment: Can you put up the HTML?

Comment: What about now?

Comment: the html is up! :)

Comment: Was already ahead of you with an update! Does it work with my most recent code?

Comment: I also put up a CSS solution which might actually be a lot easier.

Comment: does not work. although the image fades out longer the first time I hover now.

Comment: What about the CSS solution?

Comment: sorry, I must have overlooked that. Yes! It does work! Thank you!

Comment: Awesome. I'll just leave that as the answer and get rid of the JS.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that the `#Oval-1` element is being removed from the page, thus triggering the mouseout event.

Wrapping the animated element, and listening for the events on the parent like so:

```
<div id="Oval-1">
    <div id="test">hello</div>
</div>

 $(document).ready(function(){
       $('#Oval-1').mouseover(function() {
            $("#test").fadeOut();
        });
        $('#Oval-1').mouseleave(function() {
            $("#test").fadeIn();
        });
  });
```

seems to work nicely.

EDIT: Just check that the removal of the child element isn't causing the parent to collapse, potentially also triggering the mouseleave.

Added these CSS rules:

```
#test {
    position: absolute;
}

#Oval-1 {

    background: pink;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
}
```

to better illustrate if you're using a fiddle or similar.

Alternatively,

```
#Oval-1 {
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
#Oval-1:hover {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

may work

Comment: thank you. I have edited my post and also posted my html / svg. Your solution seems to get to my error, but I am not sure how to apply it with my svg, since Oval-1 is just an ellipse in my svg (which contains other elements I do not want to hide), so I cannot wrap a div around it.

Comment: Could you listen for the mouseenter on the parent SVG, or is this too large an area?

Comment: Too large unfortunately! There will be multiple ovals within this one svg which I want to hide/show depending on the mouseevents.

Comment: I think you may be better to listen for the mouse events on the ovals themselves, and use opacity rather than fadeIn in this case

Comment: can you elaborate what you mean by 'mouse events on the ovals themselves'? I'm sorry, I'm a beginner, I'm not following.

Comment: By that I meant using $('#Oval-1').mouseover, instead of $('#parent-element').mouseover. 

That said, with that solution there is no real need for jQuery as it can all be done using CSS - see last section of updated answer above!